# Bind <c:forEach><h:inputText> to a List<String>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, foreach

I want the use to enter one or more value to the JSF inputText components and then put them in a List :

```
private List<String> stringList= new ArrayList<String>();
```

I want to do something like this :

```
<c:forEach id="myData" items="#{documentController.listeColonnes}" var="address" varStatus="loop">
       <h:outputLabel value="#{address}" />
       <h:inputText value="#{documentController.stringList[loop.index]}"/>
 </c:forEach>
```

ListeColonnes has label values (ID,prenom .... )

I want to enter this values(12,sam,....) in a new arrayList ()

Any idea !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the same problem and I managed to make it work, after several trials and errors. This is was my case:

1. I wanted to create a dynamic UI that can be configured with JSON, so a took that data and put it inside a class called property.
2. After that, I need to collect the data given by the user to store it in a DB.

This was my approach:

### JSF

```
<h:form id="forma_po" styleClass="form-body" prependId="false">
    <c:forEach items="#{purchaseOrderPrinterBean.properties}" var="property">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{message_report[property.label]}:"/>
        <br/>
        <p:inputTextarea id="#{property.name}" rows="#{property.lines}"
                         cols="#{property.numberOfCharacters}" required="true"
                         maxlength="#{property.lines * property.numberOfCharacters}"
                         autoResize="false" rendered="#{property.type == 'TEXT_AREA'}"
                         value="#{purchaseOrderPrinterBean.values[property.name]}">
            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{purchaseOrderPrinterBean.fieldValue}"/>
        </p:inputTextarea>
        <p:calendar id="popup_#{property.name}" rendered="#{property.type == 'DATE'}"
                    value="#{purchaseOrderPrinterBean.values[property.name]}" required="true"
                    pattern="#{property.format}" effect="slideDown">
            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{purchaseOrderPrinterBean.fieldValue}"/>
        </p:calendar>
        <br/>
    </c:forEach>
</h:form>
```

As you can see, if the user had previously saved any data at all the I show it with the `value` attribute on both `p:inputTextarea` and `p:calendar`, this `purchaseOrderPrinterBean.values[property.name]` was of course a `java.util.HashMap<String, Object>` field, a problem I encounter with this was when the user gave or change the information, the values field did not update at all, hence the `<p:ajax />` tags inside the `p:inputTextarea` and `p:calendar`.

### Bean

In the bean I had this:

```
public void fieldValue(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() instanceof UIInput) {
        UIInput input = (UIInput) e.getSource();
        Object value = input.getValue();
        String id = input.getId();
        if(StringUtils.startsWith(id, "popup_")) {
            id = StringUtils.remove(id, "popup_");
        }
        values.put(id, value);
    }
}
```

This was the only case I found to make it work, a caution case, and I don't know why, but I had to put the prefix 'popup_' to the calendar, otherwise I got an error for duplicated ids.
Hope it helps, and excuse my bad english.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
<ui:repeat value="#{documentController.listeColonnes}" var="address" varStatus="loop">
       <h:outputLabel value="#{address}" />
       <h:inputText value="#{documentController.stringList.get(loop.index)}"/>
    </ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Don't post "Try this" answers. First try out yourself and then post it as a normal answer wherein you clearly explain the cause of the problem and how exactly it should be solved, instead of making it a seek&find game. This one only makes things worse and would fail with a `PropertyNotWritableException` on submit.